# Trying to pull text data with the keras get_file function

Tags: python, text, keras

I am currently looking at a `keras` program that tries to generate text data using a CNN. In the code provided to me by my professor, I use the function:

```
path = get_file('input.txt', origin='https://www.dropbox.com/s/2z0zdn54cqu3cqj/input.txt?dl=0')
```

This is imported using the function:

```
from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
```

Now the original text corpus provided to us was working just fine. However, whenever I changed the file `origin` inside the `get_file` function, and renamed the file name to be saved as, I started getting `HTML` code. Is there a particular reason for this? For example, I pull HTML code, even though I used `https://github.com/nlp-compromise/nlp-corpus/blob/master/poe/man_of_crowd.txt` and `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nlp-compromise/nlp-corpus/master/poe/man_of_crowd.txt`(The second link is the raw file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first link,
https://github.com/nlp-compromise/nlp-corpus/blob/master/poe/man_of_crowd.txt, even though it appears that it resolves to a text file resource, it's a `HTML` page on GitHub, which is why you get `HTML` code when downloading from this link.

As for the second raw link, https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nlp-compromise/nlp-corpus/master/poe/man_of_crowd.txt which actually points to the text file resource, when you download the file using:

```
>> from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
>> path = get_file('man_of_crowd.txt', 
                'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nlp-compromise/nlp-corpus/master/poe/man_of_crowd.txt')

Downloading data from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nlp-compromise/nlp-corpus/master/poe/man_of_crowd.txt
16384/20391 [=======================>......] - ETA: 0s
```

It actually downloads as a text file with path:

```
>> print(path)
/home/<username>/.keras/datasets/man_of_crowd.txt
```

The keras  util function really uses a six wrapper for [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html). The code for `get_file` method can be found at their GitHub repository, [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/data_utils.py#L123).

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that `'xxx.txt', origin=''` works, as just typing in `'xxx.txt', originurl''` works better.